# TextMate 2: errors when trying to compile and run a simple C program

Tags: c, xcode, gcc, textmate

#### SETUP

OS X 10.8
Xcode 4.4.1 installed
TextMate 2 -r9283

---

#### SUMMARY

Compiling and running a simple C program in TextMate2 on 10.8 with Xcode 4.4 installed gives me a path error, then a compiler error, then a linker error.

---

#### STEPS TO REPRO

1. Create a file called `test.c` in TextMate2 and save to Desktop
2. Paste this program in the `test.c` file:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   ```

   int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
       printf("Hello World\n");
       return 0;
   }
3. Type `command-R` for **Run**

---

#### EXPECTED RESULT

Output from `stdout` from running the program

---

#### ACTUAL RESULT

The TextMate output panel shows me this PATH error:

```
Can't find “gcc” on PATH.

The current PATH is:

    /usr/bin
    /bin
    /usr/sbin
    /sbin
    /Users/itod/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared/bin
Please add the directory containing “gcc” to PATH in TextMate's Shell Variables preferences.
```

then this compiler error:

```
cc1: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
```

then this linker error:

```
ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.6.o
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

How do I fix these errors and successfully compile and run a C program in TextMate 2 in OS X 10.8?

Comment: Props on a well-posed question. <3 developers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `/usr/bin/gcc` etc. properly installed, get the "Command Line Tools for Xcode" from the apple developer site http://developer.apple.com/downloads (free download with free ADC account).  It will install /usr/bin binaries for all the commandline tools - gcc, ld, etc.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I should have noticed I was missing this.

Answer (score 6):

To get TextMate 2 building and running C programs on OS X 10.8, you must udpate several environment variables in TextMate.

---

#### STEPS

1. Launch TextMate2
2. Go to Preferences (`⌘,`) > Variables
3. Enter the following name/value pairs in the table below and make sure all three pairs are "checked"

---

**`PATH`** – `$PATH:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/`

**`C_INCLUDE_PATH`** – `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/`

**`LIBRARY_PATH`** – `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/lib/`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As [dajobe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11177/dajobe) mentioned [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12032471/34934):

> If you want /usr/bin/gcc etc. properly installed, get the "Command Line Tools for Xcode"

These can also be installed via the Xcode GUI:

**Preferences > Downloads > Components > Command Line Tools > Install**

[image]